# postman.setNextRequest failing to call

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-collection-runner

I have a collection of tests which I am trying to set up to run in a certain sequence. The sequence is decided using if/else if statements which check a variable in a data-file and set the next request depending on its value.

This works well for the initial request in my collection. But when it gets to a request later in the sequence, the if statement will recognize the correct variable but skip over the postman.setNextRequest() command and run the test below it in the collection order instead of running the specified test.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Seems like a bug with the postman.setNextRequest() function.

**Request where function is working as expected:**

```
var rsp = pm.response.json();
var base = pm.environment.get('baseUrl');
pm.environment.set('id', data['appName']);
var id = pm.environment.get('id');

pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);

    pm.test("Response contains correct BaseUrl", function(){
            var issuer = rsp.issuer;
            pm.expect(issuer).to.contain(base);
            //console.log(resName);
            console.log('Passed - on to the next one!')
    });
});

if (id === 'Application/Member_PRODUCTION'||id === 'Application/B2C_PRODUCTION'||id === 'Application/Claims Transformation_PRODUCTION'){
    postman.setNextRequest('PKCE Step 1- Generate PKCE Challenge and Verifier');
}
else if (id === 'Application/sysTest_SysTest2_PRODUCTION'){
    postman.setNextRequest("oAuth Step 1 - Unauthorised API call");
}
else{
    postman.setNextRequest("oAuth Step 2- Get Session Data Key");
}
```

**Next request where the function fails to work:**

```
let cookieJar = pm.cookies.jar();

cookieJar.clear(pm.environment.get('baseUrl'));
var id = pm.environment.get('id');
console.log('oAuth check complete for application: '+ id);


pm.test("Status code is 302", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(302);
    console.log('Passed - on to the next one!')
});

if (id === 'Application/Member_PRODUCTION'){
    console.log('Next Up - SCIM Tests')
    postman.setNextRequest("SCIM Step 1 - Create Member");
}
else{
    console.log('Next Up - Login Page Test')
    postman.setNextRequest("Login Page Step 1- Get Session data key");
}
```

The request names were copied straight from the requests themselves so I don't believe that it cannot find the specified next request and the usage in both snippets above seems to be the same so I am a little stuck.

Comment: In the request where it's not working..You're saying that it hits the `if` statement, it logs to the console but then doesn't set the next request to execute?

Comment: @socalcheesehead Yep the log message appears in the console but does not execute the next request specified

Comment: You're running this in collection runner right?

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? Did you double check that the text in your `setNextRequest` function parameter is 100% correct? If you have a typo in the string, it won't trigger the request. Also, it's case sensitive, so take caution.